# Bash Scripting IF Conditions

Tags: bash, shell, grep, boolean

I need to check if the picture has a resolution of *900x900 pixels* and the filename is not allowed to contain *_thumb* or *_v*

**What I am trying to do with this line:**
If the picture ist 900x900 pixels and does not contain _v or _thumb => add the word _thumb to the end of the filename before the file extension.

**The Line it's all about:**

```
if file $picture | grep -q 900x900 && ! file $picture | grep -q _thumb && ! file $picture | grep -q _v;
```

Script:

```
#Change to current .sh directory
cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$0")"
for picture in */*/Templates/*.jpg
do
    filename=${picture##*/}
    filename1=$(echo "$filename" |sed 's/.\{4\}$//')
    parent_dir="$(dirname -- "$(/usr/local/bin/realpath "$picture")")"

    #Colors
    red=`tput setaf 1`
    green=`tput setaf 2`
    magenta=`tput setaf 5`
    reset=`tput sgr0`


    if file $picture | grep -q 900x900 && ! file $picture | grep -q _thumb && ! file $picture | grep -q _v;
        then
            mv -v "$picture" "$parent_dir/"$filename1"_thumb.jpg"
            echo "${green} [PASS] $filename1 Thumbnail 900x900 found and renamed ${reset}"
        else
            echo "${magenta} [WARNUNG] $filename1 contains _thumb already or is a _v picture or isn't 900x900 pixels ${reset}"
        fi
```

Comment: The problem is that it does not recognize the picture even if it is 900x900 and does not contain the key words.

Thanks in advance

Comment: suggest to use http://www.shellcheck.net/... for example, quote your variables.. can you try `if file "$picture" | grep -q '900x900'` without the rest of conditions and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues. #3, #4, and #5 are the most important to take a look at.

1. Target shell in your first line
2. You need to finish the `for` loop with `done`
3. You need to escape the inner double quotes on `$filename1`. The surrounding quotes currently unquote this.
4. Double quote the variables in that line
5. Clarify if you're looking for image size or just that the file has 900x900 in it? Cause `grep -q 900x900` won't find the image size. You'll need to combine it with imagemagik `identify`as others have mentioned.

With the fixes:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Change to current .sh directory
cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$0")"
for picture in */*/Templates/*.jpg 
do
    filename=${picture##*/}
    filename1=$(echo "$filename" |sed 's/.\{4\}$//')
    parent_dir="$(dirname -- "$(/usr/local/bin/realpath "$picture")")"

    #Colors
    red=`tput setaf 1`
    green=`tput setaf 2`
    magenta=`tput setaf 5`
    reset=`tput sgr0`


    if file "$picture" | grep -q 900x900 && ! file "$picture" | grep -q _thumb && ! file "$picture" | grep -q _v;
        then
            mv -v "$picture" "$parent_dir/\"$filename1\"_thumb.jpg"
            echo "${green} [PASS] $filename1 Thumbnail 900x900 found and renamed ${reset}"
        else
            echo "${magenta} [WARNING] $filename1 contains _thumb already or is a _v picture or isn't 900x900 pixels ${reset}"
        fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

do not use "file $picture | grep 900x900" because you do not know if the filename contains 900x900. I advise the use of command identify that is present in ImageMagick package like in:

```
if [[ "900 900" == $(identify -format '%w %h' "$picture") ]] ; then
  if [[ $picture != *_v.jpg && $picture != _thumb.jpg ]] ; then
    mv "$picture" "${picture%.jpg}_thumb.jpg"
  fi
fi
```

I have slightly deviate from your spec by assuming that _v and _thumb appears just before extension. I think it is more prudent to avoid unexpected matches like best_view.jpg.

PS: always check that you scripts work when there are spaces in filenames or dirnames.